# Bison generated header-guards reveal absolute paths

Tags: header-files, bison

Recent versions of Bison (I'm using 3.8.2) generate header guards which seem to be based on the absolute path of the generated header file. Since this Bison-generated code will be included in the release tarballs of our project, it is not desirable to reveal absolute paths from the machine where Bison was originally run. Is there a way to control the header guards that are generated?

Comment: As far as I know, the header guards are based on the filename as you specify it (either on the command line or as a %define). The guard macro name will be based on the absolute path if you specify an absolute path for the file location, and they will be based on the relative path if you specify a relative path. Maybe that's not practical in your build environment. An alternative would be to put the header file in `/tmp` and then move it after it is created.